# jquery jqgrid propery with dot operator

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, javascript-framework

I have a json with a property having dot "." operator in it. 
When im trying to render my grid, it comes up as blank (without any errors).

Here's my JSON:

```
{
            "total":1,
        "page":1,
        "records":2,
        "rows":[{
                "id":2110040,
                "cell":{
                "function.code":"dsadad",
                        "service.name":"dsadasda"

                }
            },
            {
                "id":2115040,
                "cell":{
                 "function.code":"iuiyuiy",
                     "service.name":"iyuiyuiy"

                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

this is my colModel

```
colModel : [ {
        name : 'service.name',
        search : 'true',
        editable : true,
        //index : 'service.name',
        width : 200,
        jsonmap : "cell.service.name"           
    },
    {
        name : 'function.code',
        search : 'true',
        editable : true,
        sortable:true,
        //index : 'function.code',
        width : 200,
        jsonmap : "cell.function.code"          
    }],
```

JSON reader is:

```
jsonReader : {
        repeatitems : false,
        root : "rows",
        cell : "cell",
        id : "id",
        page : "page",
        records : "records"
    },
```

Please help,what am i missing here ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find you question interesting. It's close to the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426670/how-to-map-an-xml-in-jqgrid/6432367#6432367), but in case of JSON instead of XML.

The problem is that jqGrid try to read rows with respect of `obj.cell.function.code` instead of `obj.cell['function.code']`. To let jqGrid to read the data correctly you can use **functions as the `jsonmap`**:

```
colModel: [
    {
        name: 'service_name',
        search: 'true',
        editable: true,
        width: 200,
        jsonmap: function (obj) {
            return obj.cell['service.name'];
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'function_code',
        search: 'true',
        editable: true,
        sortable: true,
        width: 200,
        jsonmap: function (obj) {
            return obj.cell['function.code'];
        }
    }
]
```

How you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user620339.htm) the approach work.

Comment: @user620339: By the way [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user620339_old.htm) from [your old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853457/jquery-jqgrid-renders-empty-table/6905206#6905206) works also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
colModel : [ {
        name : 'service.name',
        search : 'true',
        editable : true,
        //index : 'service.name',
        width : 200,
        jsonmap : 'cell["service.name"]'           
    },
    {
        name : 'function.code',
        search : 'true',
        editable : true,
        sortable:true,
        //index : 'function.code',
        width : 200,
        jsonmap : 'cell["function.code"]'          
    }],
```

Comment: Then I think you cannot use dot in property name of a json object. You might use underscore or someother character like $. Take a look at this [link](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Property_Name_Format#Property_Name_Format)

Comment: Not sure if JSON itself is the reason or is it JqGrid, because I was using flexigrid before this with same JSON format.  Anyways, thanks for your help Shankar.