# how do i remove extra space from jqgird edit field value in edit form of jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, edit, jqgrid-asp.net

In `jqGrid` when we click on `Edit` button then `jqGrid` loads data in the `Edit` Form with extra spaces at the end of the field. for example when i see the `username` then its looks like as under:

```
Username: farhan(space)(space)(space)(space)(space)
```

How do i remove extra space from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you fill the grid? Come the data from the database where you use `char` instead of `varchar` SQL type? Is it not better to trim the texts already on the server side before placing it in the JSON response used to fill the grid? One more possibility to cut the spaces exist on the client side. You can use `jsonmap` to do this (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902936/jquery-jqgrid-propery-with-dot-operator/6904980#6904980) for example)

If you really need to cut the spaces only in the form dialog you can use [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) or [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) to modify the form contain. You can find the `<input>` element by `id` for example. The `id` will be the same as the `name` property from the corresponding column of the `colModel`. So you can get the current value, call [$.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) and set the result as the new value of the `<input>` element.